# Call a function inside ngFor in Angular 9 lose context

Tags: angular, this, apply, ngfor, angular9

I have updated my Angular project from 8.3 to **angular 9** but now I'm loosing the context in a function called in a ngFor. I used **apply** to set my context:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myMenu;">
  <button (click)="item.function.apply(this, [item])">{{item.label}}</button>
</div>
```

In my ts I set my array in this way:

```
this.myMenu.push({
  id: '1',
  label: 'ONE',
  function: this.one
});
this.myMenu.push({
  id: '2',
  label: 'TWO',
  function: this.two
});
```

And those are my functions to call:

```
  myThisOne: 'One';
  myThisTwo: 'Two';

  one(item) {
    console.log('id: ' + item.id + ', myThisOne: ' + this.myThisOne);
  }

  two(item) {
    console.log('id: ' + item.id + ', myThisTwo: ' + this.myThisTwo);
  }
```

But I get **undefined**. I can't read my variables in my AppComponent, in console:

```
id: 1, myThisOne: undefined
id: 2, myThisTwo: undefined
```

What is it changed in Angular 9? How can i use this in my function? You can try it on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9-abstract-n2ydes).

Comment: what happened after you added the `apply(this, [item])` ?

Comment: @FahdLihidheb with Angular 9 with apply 'this' is the item, without 'this' is myMenu. In both case I can't read my variables in AppComponent.

Comment: Is using `apply()` a must in angular 9 ? the `this` is set to the component in angular 7 (and 8) without `apply()`.

Comment: No, my main goal is to call a function defined in my AppComponent that can access to the same context.

Comment: you want to set the `this` (context) to the item ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a use of bind method to bind the function to the this context.

```
 this.myMenu.push({
  id: '1',
  label: 'ONE',
  function: this.one.bind(this)
});
this.myMenu.push({
  id: '2',
  label: 'TWO',
  function: this.two.bind(this)
});
```

In the template you will need following changes.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of myMenu;">
  <button (click)="item.function(item)">{{item.label}}</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't provide alot of informations so i am going to suppose that both functions `one()` and `two()` are in a **Component.ts** file. that said.

You want to change the context in your function to point to each item. but here i see that `myThisOne = 'One'; myThisTwo = 'Two';` (pointed by @Alon) are defined in your component so they would be `undefined` if you try to access them from one of the item.

You should add them inside your items. this way your binding will work.

```
 this.myMenu.push({
  id: '1',
  myThisOne: 'one', // here
  label: 'ONE',
  function: this.one.bind(this)
});
this.myMenu.push({
  id: '2',
  myThisTwo: 'two', // and here
  label: 'TWO',
  function: this.two.bind(this)
});
```

Comment: The example was simplified, the real problem was and I could not access to my services (like Router) injected in my costructor. Putting .bind(this) solved the error :)

Answer (score 0):

Everything should work fine with the `apply` method, there is a problem in the following code:

```
myThisOne: 'One';
myThisTwo: 'Two';
```

With the above syntax you are defining `myThisOne` and `myThisTwo` and their types but you're not initializing them. If i understand your intention, the code should be:

```
myThisOne = 'One';
myThisTwo = 'Two';
```

Comment: You are right but it was just an error when I wrote the simplified example on stackblitz.